# d3.js - Select all the rectangles on svg

Tags: d3.js

I have the following:

```
    <svg id="svggraph">
        <g transform="translate(50,10)">
<text fill="brown" font-size="30px" font-family="sans-serif" height="20" width="25" y="30" x="0" style="text-decoration:underline">A</text>
    <text fill="brown" font-size="30px" font-family="sans-serif" height="20" width="25" y="30" x="22" style="text-decoration:underline">B</text>
<text fill="brown" font-size="30px" font-family="sans-serif" height="20" width="25" y="30" x="44" style="text-decoration:underline">C</text>
<text fill="brown" font-size="30px" font-family="sans-serif" height="20" width="25" y="30" x="66" style="text-decoration:underline">D</text>
    <rect style="stroke: black;" height="25" width="20" y="40" x="0" id="checkins1"></rect><rect style="stroke: black;" height="25" width="20" y="40" x="22" id="builds2"></rect>
    <rect style="stroke: black;" height="25" width="20" y="40" x="44" id="oss3">
    </rect><rect style="stroke: black;" height="25" width="20" y="40" x="66" id="appsec4"></rect><rect 
    </svg>
```

I would like to fetch all the rectangles from this svg. I am trying the following:

```
var svgdata = d3.select("#svggraph");
 var svgrectdata = svgdata.selectAll("rect");
```

However i am not getting the rect data. I need to fetch all the rectangles so that i can loop through the rect and based on ids i can change the color.

Comment: Works for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/NLF38/

Comment: found the bug... i was calling outside the scope.

Comment: svgrectdata.attr("fill", fillColor(this)); function fillColor(x)
{


     console.log(x); 
} this is not working. can we not pass this as parameter

Comment: Yes we can -- http://jsfiddle.net/NLF38/1/

Comment: thanks lars!!! it is working fine.